# DotNetOpenAuth oAuth in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to understand how to apply the oAuth consumer library from [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) in the context of ASP.NET MVC.

oAuth is new to me, and the library doesn't seem very simple. Does anyone have a sample of leveraging this library, for this usage, in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at the sample projects that come along with the [DotNetOpenAuth source code](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net).

The solution obtained on unzipping has several sample projects in it. One of them is an Oauth consumer implementation. Though it is a ASP.NET Webforms application, reimplementing it as an ASP.NET MVC application shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: dead link, it's here instead: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at Rob Conery's TekPub [ASP.Net MVC 2.0 Starter Site](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/05/24/mvc-starter-2).  He has setup DotNetOpenAuth as part of that.  It should point you in the right direction

**EDIT**
My assumption was based on the the fact the OpenID and OAuth are the same. They are not the same but complimentary ideas.  OpenId is about Authentication where as OAuth is about Authorization.

While not directly related to ASP.NET MVC the [TweetSharp Library](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) has an OAuth implementation written in C# that may be of some use.

[TweetSharp OAuth workflow](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OAuthWorkflow&referringTitle=Documentation)
[Simple OAuth integration for Twitter in ASP.NET MVC](http://craigtech.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/simple-oauth-integration-for-twitter-in-asp-net-mvc/)

[OAuth with Silverlight for Windows Phone 7](http://blog.markarteaga.com/OAuthWithSilverlightForWindowsPhone7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link Nathan, however it doesn't appear that Rob has any oAuth implementation in the Starter Site.

Comment: @nikmd23 I did make the assumtion that OpenId and OAuth are the same.  My apologies if that is not the case. Have a look in the Controllers/SessionController Authenticate method and the Views/Session/Create.aspx file. The implementation that I was referring to is there.

Comment: Added a couple of links that may be of value

Answer (score 12):

I've recently created a NuGet package that adds auth with Facebook, Twitter, Google to any ASP.NET MVC 3 page - in a very simple and extensible manner - and it's based on DotNetOpenAuth. Take a look:

https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleSocialAuth.MVC3/

and the source is on github:

https://github.com/rafek/SimpleSocialAuth

Comment: does this support MVC 4? the NuGet package seems to be MVC3

Comment: @GreyCloud some guys are working on an MVC4 branch, check it on GitHub

Answer (score 4):

There are now tutorials online that show how to do this.  Here is one: [OpenID and OAuth using DotNetOpenAuth in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/08/openid-and-oauth-using-dotnetopenauth-in-asp-net-mvc/) from Random Sparks