# ASP.net MVC 3 user registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, registration, membership-provider, user-profile

I am new to **asp.net mvc 3** world
I looked at some tutorials to get started. I want to know what is the best option to manage users?

I intended use of the membership provider (and modify this for extend the default fields)
or use the user  profiling + membership provider?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these? 
once I made ​​my application the idea is create a mobile application: a user must be able access by user and password (my web application)... it affects my choice?

Comment: `I am new to asp.net mvc 3.5 world`. Such world doesn't exist. There is ASP.NET MVC 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and a developer preview of 4.0. Never heard of 3.5.

Comment: ok sorry! ....for asp.net mvc 30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from here :

http://www.asp.net/mvc

You can take advantage of a sample application :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

And the following one is specific to membership :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-7

I would also consider integrating OpenAuth.

[DotNetOpenAuth oAuth in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909237/dotnetopenauth-oauth-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Another good example is the NerdDinner project.

Site: http://www.nerddinner.com

Source Code: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com